# How do I render a PNG with transparency in LibGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx, lwjgl, transparency

I'm building a simple tic-tac-toe example with LibGDX. I have simple images: cross, circle and board, all `png`s created with GIMP with a transparent background.

How can I render them as a `Texture` with transparency?

I've tried with GL10 enable feature, but it seems not to work.

Comment: Have you put this in your code : Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
   Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

Comment: put this in the render loop

Comment: It should work fine (does for me). What specific problem did you run into?

Comment: Your statement: *"I have simple images: cross, circle and board all pngs created with gimp with alpha as color."* could be interpreted ***many*** different ways, from color-key transparency to pre-multiplied alpha. Can you clarify what you mean? Generally you are either going to need alpha blending (alpha transparency) or alpha testing (alpha mask); neither of these things are enabled by default and the second is not supported in modern OpenGL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SpriteBatch#enableBlending](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html#enableBlending%28%29)

before rendering:

```
batch.enableBlending();
batch.begin();
//draw stuff
batch.end();
```

Answer (score 2):

Create Sprite and assign Texture to it, Then use Sprite setColor to adjust its alpha, like so,

```
Texture yourTexture = new Texture("image.png");
sprite = new Sprite(yourTexture);
//RGBA
sprite.setColor(1, 0, 0, 0.2f);
```

and in render() loop use SpriteBatch

```
sprite.draw(spriteBatch);
```

Comment: Note that SpriteBatch uses DefaultShader, if you would like you might write your own shader to control transparency, and of course you should enable OpenGL ES 2.0 for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you put

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1); 
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

at the beginning of your render() loop is should refresh the screen with the colour black. So if any images have transparency in them it will be noticeable.

so your render() loop would possibly look like this

```
public void render(float delta) {
  Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
  Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  // Update logic & etc.        

  batch.begin();

  // Place your render calls
  // In this I use a Sprite object named "sprite" and all you need to do is call .draw();
  // on it and it will render at 0,0, unless told differently with .setPosition();

  sprite.draw(batch);

  batch.end();              
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to render a .png with transparency as well. With the basic setup (blending not activated) it didn't render properly.

I never activated blending, but I did add this:

```
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_ALPHA_BITS);
```

My issue was the alpha was never cleared. Meaning if I rendered with 0.1 alpha, it would take 10 frames until the alpha was "stacked" back up to 1. Adding the call above cleared the alpha, just like you would clear color.

I know this is an old question, so the solutions then were different. enableBlending should still work, but I am not sure if this prevents "stacking" of alpha. Clearing the alpha bits is probably the easiest way to prevent the solid look.

As for the actual rendering, that is the same as always.

```
//Viewport, camera, logic, etc
batch.begin();
//draw your image(s) here
batch.end();
```